# Cannot deploy symfony app to Heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku

At first, sorry for stupid question but I'm new in Heroku as in Symfony. I'm learning Symfony and now trying to deploy my app to Heroku. But after push to heroku I have error I can't solve. I searched for answers but didn't find the solution. My enviroment is switched to PROD. Here is bunch of files I think can be usefull to analyze.

```
    Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 8783, done.
Delta compression using up to 3 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7959/7959), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8783/8783), 6.34 MiB | 499.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8783 (delta 2737), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> PHP app detected
-----> Resolved composer.lock requirement for PHP >=5.3.3 to version 5.6.2.
-----> Installing system packages...
       - PHP 5.6.2
       - Apache 2.4.10
       - Nginx 1.6.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
       - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled, using 'ext-zend-opcache.ini')
-----> Installing dependencies...
       Composer version 1.0-dev (a309e1d89ded6919935a842faeaed8e888fbfe37) 2014-10-20 19:16:14

 !     WARNING: You have put Composer's vendor directory under version control.
       That directory should not be in your Git repository; only composer.json
       and composer.lock should be added, with Composer handling installation.
       Please 'git rm --cached vendor/' to remove the folder from your index,
       then add '/vendor/' to your '.gitignore' list to remove this notice.
       For more information, refer to the Composer FAQ: http://bit.ly/1rlCSZU

       Loading composer repositories with package information
       Installing dependencies from lock file
         - Removing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.4.0)
       Generating optimized autoload files
       Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
       PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /tmp/build_a721f054a4c0177a8e4e060c5b747b1c/app/AppKernel.php on line 26
       Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]



 !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

Here is composer.json content:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

and AppKernel.php content:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Irishdash\StorageBundle\IrishdashStorageBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please follow the instructions received in the warning by Heroku.

> Please 'git rm --cached vendor/' to remove the folder from your index,
>          then add '/vendor/' to your '.gitignore'

Then commit the changes for the .gitignore file to Git.

Next, it's installing dependencies from the lock file, but looks like you've moved the `sensio/generator-bundle` package to `require` from `require-dev`.

Given this, try running `php composer.phar update` and then commit the changes for the `composer.lock` file to Git.

Comment: And obviously, `$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();` and `$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();` both need to be in the regular `$bundles` array in `AppKernel.php`.

Answer (score 11):

You want to run `heroku config:set SYMFONY_ENV=prod` before you push, otherwise the `post-install-cmd` scripts will run in the `dev` environment, which needs the generator bundle, but that one is not available as Heroku only installs packages from `require`, not from `require-dev`, during a push (using Composer's `--no-dev` mode).

Answer (score 0):

Also you may need composer.lock file in your app